# Ensuring CSS exact size when printing

Tags: css, printing

I have the following simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#card
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width:  65mm;
            height: 65mm;
        }
        div#circle
        {
            width:  20mm;
            height: 20mm;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-top: 5mm;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="card"></div>
    <div id="circle"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

When printing the page, I expect it to output a 65mm square, but it is 70mm and the circle is also a bit bigger than 20mm. How to ensure an exact printing size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make our web page print-friendly, we need to use separate css for print like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

The above css will be applicable for only at the time of printing web pages.

Please refer the following links for more details:

http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm

http://www.killersites.com/articles/newsletterArchive/Newsletter_Nov3_2003.htm

http://envisionic.com/webtips/user_experience/printer_friendly.php